# understanding global object in relation with this keyword in nodeJs

Tags: node.js

with regards to this keyword in nodeJs,

1. `this`  refers to the global object in global context
2. in a function, `this`  refers to the global object by default

If we have to expose a variable globally then we do it through module.exports.

I am not understanding why `this.name` in the `hello` function results in `undefined` but
`this.name` in console.log returns the correct value

```
module.exports.name = 'Per';

const hello = function () {
    console.log(this.name);
}

//outputs Per
console.log(this.name);

//outputs undefined
hello();
```

I am new to nodeJs and this might be a duplicate question too, in that case would be great if someone points me to the questions already answered in this context here

If I do something like this,

```
const hello2 = hello.bind(module.exports);
hello2();
```

that outputs the `name` variable value.

Comment: A full-on `function(){}` declaration comes with its own `this`, so it's not defined there regardless, as it was never set. Replace that method with `() => console.log( this.name )` and it should output `Per` again, as an arrow function does not come with its own context like that. But I think it would be better to just use variables declared with `const` and `let` inside your modules, and not rely on `global scope` altogether, but just your `module scope`.

Comment: Honestly, while the question for `this` in Node functions is an OK one (even if duplicate) this part: "*is there any other way to add variables to global scope than the*" just leans heavily on this whole thing being [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Global variables have been deemed a code smell and an anti-pattern for decades. While modules can have "globals" (confined to the module) and that's actually OK (since it's restricted) what you seem to want is *application-wide* globals which is a huge red flag.

Comment: @VLAZ yes I shouldn't have added that in the end, but this is not a real application I was testing some concepts I learnt about the this keyword , hence the example

Comment: @somethinghere okay so it is more about how I used it  (as a full-on function) , the arrow function call works , thanks a lot